# Microsoft Outlook import ICS with STATUS

Tags: python, outlook, icalendar, outlook-calendar

I would like to import a Python generated ICS file (with [ics 0.7](https://pypi.org/project/ics/)) into Outlook. But unfortunately the status attribute is not used by Outlook. How can I set it so that when I import the ICS file into Outlook the event is set to Confirmed?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:ics.py - http://git.io/lLljaA

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20220331T131500Z
LOCATION:2.013
DTSTART:20220331T114500Z
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Your text here
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

I have tried to manually change the PRODID to:
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN
and then add the following attribute:
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
but without success.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS` header. The possible values are `FREE`, `WORKINGELSEWHERE`, `TENTATIVE`, `BUSY`, `OOF`.